# How to pass and insert Records from lightning web component to apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, record, insert, js

With this code I tried to insert into my object but I get this error :

`System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

=> My Apex Class

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=false)
        public static Boolean insertFieldSynchro(sObject NContra) {
            insert NContra;
            return true;
        }
```

=> JS

```
 if(selectedRecords.length > 0){ 
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedRecords.length; i++) {
                selectedRecords[i].sobjectType="NContra__c";
                selectedRecords[i].New_Contrad__c = this.recordId;
                try{
                    insertFieldSynchro(selectedRecords[i]);
                    console.log('Insertion OK');
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log('error insertFieldSynchro : ' + JSON.stringify(e));
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation on how to **[Call Apex Methods Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative)**, you will see that you pass parameters to Apex using name/value pairs. Note also that it is a `Promise` architecture, so the logic does not execute synchronously.

**Incorrect**

```
insertFieldSynchro(selectedRecords[i]);
```

**Correct**

```
insertFieldSynchro({ NContra: selectedRecords[i] });
```

Please note that the spelling of the parameter name has to be exact, and is case-sensitive. Because of that, I strongly recommend you only use whole words.